# Fetch the token only after refreshing the page. Token returns null before refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the component `Items` in`componentDidMount ()` I try to call two functions. Fetch from localStorage `domain` -> returns me the domain --> it's ok. When fetch from localStorage, `token` returns me`null`. Only when I refresh the page will it get the token value.

**Login**

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url, 
      data, 
      config
    }) 
      .then(res => { 
        const instanceSingle = res.data.instances.map((instance, index) => {
          return instance.domain
        });
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            instances: res.data.instances
          }, this.getDomain(instanceSingle))
        } 
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  getDomain = (domain) => {

    localStorage.setItem('domain', domain);

    this.getToken();
  }

  getToken = () => {

    const domain = localStorage.getItem('domain');
    const url = '${domain}/oauth2/token';

    axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url, 
      data, 
      config
    }) 
      .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data['access_token']))     
        } 
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
      });

  }


  render () {
    const {instances} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.token || instances.length === 1 ?
          <Items
            token= {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))}
            domain={localStorage.getItem('domain')}
            instances={this.state.instances}
          />
          :
           instances.length > 2 ?
            <AnotherComponent      
            />
            :
            <form method="post" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <input type="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                            />
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password"
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChange={this.handleUserInput}  />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit">Log in</button>          
            </form>    
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Items**

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    const domain = localStorage.getItem('domain');

        axios({
            url: `${domain}/api/v1/items`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                items: response.data
            });
            this.function2();
            this.function1();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                            <Item

                            />
                    )}    
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three options just try with those :

1. you have set the instances after you make a call for login, that means in react when you change the state render will automatically call after state change.
   thats why `this.state.token || instances.length === 1` your second or condition is executed even if the token is not set into the state. and your child component is not getting token value as props from the Login component
2. you have used conditional component rendering for Items and another component thats why it is always mounting even only instances field is going to change in state thats why set your `instances` and `token` state at same time rather than both are in different line.
3. If you dont want to fail your code then put && rather than the || because from your code instances are getting value but token is not getting value. And as per your code in componentDidMount you must require token then why you are taking risk of token is getting null, just put `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with 2 async fetch calls, but when you're setting state with

```js
this.setState({
  instances: res.data.instances
}, this.getDomain(instanceSingle))
```

only `domain` is set in localStorage by `getDomain()` which is then triggering the second async call to get the token:

```js
getDomain = (domain) => {

  localStorage.setItem('domain', domain);

  this.getToken(); // second async call
}
```

maybe it would be a better idea to call `setState` individually in `getDomain()` and `getToken()`? E.g. something in this direction:

```js
getDomain = (domain) => {

  localStorage.setItem('domain', domain);

  this.setState({domain: domain});

  this.getToken(); // second async call
}
```

and

```js
getToken = () => {
  // ...
    .then(res => { 
      if (res.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data['access_token']));
        this.setState({token: localStorage.getItem('token')});
      } 
    }).catch(err => { 
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

and then in `onSubmit` maybe just this:

```js
this.setState({
  instances: res.data.instances
});
this.getDomain(instanceSingle);
```

Comment: In component `Items` console.log error return me `TypeError: baseURL.replace is not a function
    at combineURLs (combineURLs.js?e683:12)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js?5270:30)`. in network tab i don't see request `${domain}/api/v1/items` in component `Items` in componenDidMount()

Comment: does that happen with your original code above or did you change something?

Comment: I think that problem is that domain in localstorage is in quotes. How can I delete these quotes?

Comment: I think you forgot the backticks in your `getTocken()` method, e.g. `const url = '${domain}/oauth2/token';`  should be in backticks!

Comment: I have in backticks. I have token saved in localstorage. Problem isn't in '${domain}/oauth2/token';   Problem is in  `${domain}/api/v1/items`, in component `Items`

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(`${domain}/api/v1/items`) before you make the request?

Comment: Where I have to put `console.log(${domain}/api/v1/items)` in componentDidMount() ?

Comment: nowhere =), but what output do you get if you add it before you axios call in componentDidMount()?

Comment: I did as you wrote. Does not load from localstorage the domain and token  now.

Comment: Return me domain localhost and token null